# How to update UI from background thread in a fragment

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, fragment

I have an app that has a Fragment with a ListView. I ping IP addresses on the network and when I get a response I add the IP address to a list. Once I've finished pinging the IP addresses, I put this list of IP addresses that replied to my ping into a ListView.

What I want to do is update this ListView as I'm pinging rather than doing after I've pinged all the IP addresses. To ping the IP addresses I'm using an AsyncTask which then calls a Runnable Thread. How do I tell the Fragment to update the UI from that Runnable class when I find an IP address?

The rough layout of my classes is below.

```
public class FinderFragment extends ListFragment {

    private void CallFind(){
        new Find().execute();
    }

    private class Find extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            SearchNetwork searchNetwork = new SearchNetwork(ipAddress);
            try {
                searchNetwork.StartFind();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            UpdateDeviceList();
        }
    }
}

public class SearchNetwork {

    public void StartFind() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t[] = new Thread[20];
        for(int i=0; i<02; i++){
            t[i] = new Thread(new FindDevices(i*5));
            t[i].start();
        }
        for(Thread thread : t){
            thread.join();
        }
    }

    class FindDevices implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Ping the IP addresses here
            //I want to update UI from here
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried `getActivity().runOnUiThread` ?

Comment: use handler instead of it please refer the threadSample example of google sample.https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this....

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
               // Do whatever you want
               }
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

use **Handler**, **runOnUiThread** or **View.post**

```
android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //update here
            }
        });
```

Comment: Sorry, I've only just really started learning about Threads and AsyncTasks and still don't completely understand them. Would that handler go in my FinderFragment class?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask) instead of raw threads! There is a method `onPostExecute()` which runs on the main UI thread and that's the point where you can update your UI ...

But you have to keep in mind, that you have to cancel the AsyncTask (threads as well) if the fragment gets destroyed, otherwise your task will continue to run and will try to change the UI of the fragment, but the fragment doesn't exist anymore which will lead to exceptions like `IllegalStateException: Fragment not attached to Activity` or `View Not Attached Exceptions`

Comment: I'm doing that at the moment. I use onPostExecute() but that updates the ListView once doInBackground is finished. I want to update the ListView while doInBackground is running.

Comment: wtf? Obviously you do in `doInBackground()` you do your work and update the list afterwards in `onPostExecute()`. Im not sure what you mean with "updating the ListView once doInBackground()" ... You could run 20 AsyncTasks and each of them is loading data in `doInBackground()` and updating the ListView afterwards in `onPostExecute()` or you could write a single AsyncTask which will run 20 times findDevices and use AsyncTasks `onProgressUpdate()` which allows you to partially update the UI (runs on main UI Thread) from doInBackground() , where  `onPostExecute()` is called only once after all

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Handler`, `runOnUiThread`, `postDelayed` and `AsyncTask`.
`AsyncTask` is good option other than rest as it extends the handler class.
When you have to code in thread use the `doInBackground()` method like this:

```
class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask(Void,Void,Void){
    public doInBackground(){
        // do your code here
    }
}
```

And call it on the UI thread like this:

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to auto update every x sec you can use this:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(refreshing){
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //do your stuff here
                    }
                });
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(30000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`publishProgress()`

and catch it in the overidden method

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
```